# Iterating through multiple URLs from .txt file with Python/BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to create a script that takes a .txt file with multiple lines of YouTube usernames, appends it to the YouTube user homepage URL, and crawls through to get profile data.

The code below gives me the info I want for one user, but I have no idea where to start for importing and iterating through multiple URLs.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -- coding: utf-8 --
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib2

# download the page
response = urllib2.urlopen("http://youtube.com/user/alxlvt")
html = response.read()

# create a beautiful soup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# find the profile info & display it
profileinfo = soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "user-profile-item" })
for info in profileinfo:
    print info.get_text()
```

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Eg., if I had a .txt file that read:

```
username1
username2
username3
etc.
```

How could I go about iterating through those, appending them to http://youtube.com/user/%s, and creating a loop to pull all the info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use an actual scraping module (like scrapy, mechanize, selenium, etc), you can just keep iterating on what you've written.

1. *use the iteration on file objects to read line by line* A few things, a neat fact about file objects, is that, if they are opened with 'rb', they actually call readline() as their iterator, so you can just do `for line in file_obj` to go line by line in a document.
2. *concatenate urls* I used `+` below, but you can also use the concatenate function.
3. *make a list of urls* - will let you stagger your requests, so you can do [compassionate screen scraping.](http://dev.lethain.com/an-introduction-to-compassionate-screenscraping/)

   ```
   # Goal: make a list of urls
   url_list = []

   # use a try-finally to make sure you close your file.
   try:
       f = open('pathtofile.txt','rb')
       for line in f:
           url_list.append('http://youtube.com/user/%s' % line)
       # do something with url list (like call a scraper, or use urllib2
   finally:
       f.close()
   ```

EDIT: Andrew G's string format is clearer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to open the file (preferably with the `with open('/path/to/file', 'r') as f:` syntax) and then do `f.readline()` in a loop.  Assign the results of readline() to a string like "username" and then run your current code inside the loop, starting with `response = urllib2.urlopen("http://youtube.com/user/%s" % username)`.